# Starting Activity from non-activity class and passing context to it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

I know that this is common question, but can't find my mistake.
I need to pass Activity's Context to the RestClient class, which is non-activity. I do it like this:

```
public class RestClient {
 public void setContextRest(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
    }
    public Context getContextRest()
    {
        return  this.context;
    }
    public RestClient(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

and in my Activity class :

```
 RestClient helper = new RestClient(LoginActivity.this);
 helper.setContextRest(LoginActivity.this);
```

and this is how I get it in the RestClient:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
i.putExtra("relogin", true);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

and I get

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2823)
    at com.library.RestClient.Execute(RestClient.java:276)
    at com.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:46)
at com.library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:76)
    at com.assignmentexpert.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:318)
    at com.assignmentexpert.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
```

in the `Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);`. The problem is that `context` is null on some reason. Tell me please what it is?

Comment: you are passing null for sure.

Comment: if you are using RestClient constructor to initialize context variable then no need to call setContextRest from your LoginActivity Activity

Comment: Also when passing around a context in your application you should try to use Activity.getApplicationContext() whenever possible. Using activities as a context might result in that activity being kept in memory for much longer time than it would otherwise need to, causing memory issues.

Comment: Have you checked and tried with the solution which I have posted? Most probably that will solve your issue for getting context in client class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its  contradicts right designing patterns, but I used Singletone for my Activity and it works properly. Like this:

```
      public static Context getInstance(){
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = LoginActivity._context;
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your RestClient in this way:

```
public class RestClient {
    Context context;

    public RestClient(Context mcontext) {
       context = mcontext;
    }
    ....
    .... 
}
```

Now, initialize your restclient like this:

```
RestClient client;
client = new RestClient(getApplicationContext());
```

It will allow you to access context anywhere in your RestClient class.

Comment: Best answer.I was going to provide this same answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Intent i = new Intent(this.context, LoginActivity.class);
```

it should this.context instead of just context